# Distinguishing submit buttons in separate forms with PHP

Tags: php, html

If one has multiple input forms, is there a way for one to distinguish one submit button from the other? The reason is I have two forms and each form performs a different task.

Both forms do a submit and each submit will perform an SQL query. The first one is a *SELECT FROM* query to do a search for data and the second will do *UPDATE* or *DELETE* (using this code on two different pages) query.

Comment: You have to give the distinct name to the given submit buttons and check with `isset($_POST['btn_name'])`

Comment: Both form have same action url? If so, then you can use different name for buttons.

Answer (score 1):

There might be many cases
**First:** if all the forms have the same **action** attribute then you will have to name the submit buttons differently.
**second:** If the forms have different actions then there is no need to  name the buttons differently. You can achieve the task with the same name.
Three: if you want some of the fileds to have a different form action in your form then you can try this

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
  <input type="submit" formaction="demo_admin.asp"
  value="Submit as admin">
</form>
```

To learn about form action overriding click [here](http://w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

- Give each form a hidden input with a unique name.
- Give the submit buttons different names

Answer (score 0):

you specify the `<input type="submit" name="form1" />`

that name part is the way to specify seperately to php